# calling nested button function in jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i am trying to call `start` button from `restart` like below it is not working how can i achieve it ? as it is working in cancel button case

```
        $( "#flash_screen" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 1050,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Start": function() { alert('start');
                },

                restart: function(){

                $( this ).dialog( "Start" );

                },

                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                close: function() {
                allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually calling the Close function - you are passing "close" command to the `dialog`, which calls the defined `close` event handler.

To do what you want, you should create a separate `Start` function that you assign as both the `restart` and `start` event handlers:

```
function startHandler () { alert('start'); }

$( "#flash_screen" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 1050,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Start": startHandler,

            restart: startHandler,

            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: function() {
            allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
            }
        });
```